# Login Using Touchscreen

Tags: boot-issues, touchscreen, keyboard, login, pixel

I am using a pi2 with Pixel as an air-gapped computer for secure data entry. In order to ensure that it remains isolated I have covered all the ports and cable jacks. The only input is a camera for reading QR-Codes and a touchscreen. I am using the matchbox virtual keyboard. My problem is first, that the login screen does not show up on boot, and second, if it did show up, the user would not be able to enter a password because the matchbox keyboard does not show itself unless the user selects it from the start menu which is unavailable until after login. How can a pi be setup such that the user will be presented with a login screen upon bootup and such that the matchbox virtual keyboard will be available. Thanks, John

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have the virtual keyboard working at the login screen.
The solution is to install the GDM3 display manager
The display manager is responsible for managing the user authentication screen. The Raspian OS comes with the LightDM display manager which does not have a virtual keyboard for password entry. The Florence virtual keyboard we just installed will not work either because there is no apparent way to load it before the login screen shows up. Same problem with Matchbox-keyboard. So we will switch out LightDM with GDM3 which does have an integrated virtual keyboard.

This is the post I found which solved the problem.
https://askubuntu.com/questions/829108/ ... emove-them

Basically though: just do the following.
Execute the following commands in your pi's terminal window.
`sudo apt-get update`
`sudo apt-get install gdm3`

This is a long install during which you will be asked to verify switching from LightDM to GDM3.

After the install, reboot. You should get a new login screen with a virtual keyboard if you set raspi-config to require the user to sign in.

In my case the Florence keyboard was already installed on my pi but really don't think it makes a difference as far as the login goes because GDM3 uses it's own virtual keyboard. Generally speaking though, I like the Florence virtual keyboard much better than Matchbox

Comment: Please accept your own answer with a click on the tick on its left side. Only this will finish the question and it will not pop up again year for year.